# WCF FlatWSDL - Where do you stick the necessary code if your host is IIS?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, wsdl

Basically, looking into the solutions to get a FlatWSDL, I found the following:

- http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2007/05/improving-wcf-interoperability-flattening-your-wsdl.html
- http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/

The WCF Extras looks interesting, but might be too much for what I need (which is simply a FlatWSDL). So, the first link points out how to do that, except here's the thing. If you host your service within IIS, where would this code go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question (over a year old!) but as I've been playing with this today, I thought it would be worth trying to clear up this question...

The answer is from here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/23/flatten-your-wsdl-with-this-custom-servicehost-for-wcf.aspx

As described on that page you need to create 3 classes - *FlatWsdl*, *FlatWsdlServiceHost* and *FlatWsdlServiceHostFactory*. Then for hosting in IIS, add a reference to the Factory class into the .svc markup file...

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#"
  Factory="{YourNamespace}.FlatWsdlServiceHostFactory"
  Service="{YourNamespace}.WcfService1"%>
```

Also, it looks like this will be solved in WCF 4.5 :)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/piyushjo/archive/2011/10/05/what-s-new-in-wcf-4-5-flat-wsdl-support.aspx

Comment: Yea, I just wished they named it better. `?FlatWsdl` would be better than `?singleWsdl`

Answer (score 0):

ServiceHostFactory is the answer, described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702697.aspx